# Does the application integration OneDrive need commit to reviewed?

Tags: onedrive

My ios application integration OneDrive use Microsoft Graph API,But there is no place to tell me whether the application release needs to be reviewed by Microsoft or not. Similar to google drive, dropbox needs to be submitted to their review team for review. It seems a bit odd that Onedrive doesn't have this step.Can anyone tell me if anyone has a similar experience?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJGLU.png)

1. I read search all the relate doc from Microsoft Graph
2. I have search the topic in the internet

Answer (score -1):

I check the documentation provided and also did the same earlier.
So, as per my experience and according to information provided on Microsoft's integration page for OneDrive, there is no mention of a need for review before an app can be released. This suggests that there may not be a requirement for review by Microsoft before releasing an app that integrates OneDrive through the Microsoft Graph API. However, it is still recommended to thoroughly test and ensure that the integration of OneDrive in the app complies with all relevant guidelines and policies to avoid any issues. Additionally, it is always a good idea to check with Microsoft support for any specific questions or concerns regarding app integration with OneDrive.